# Creating jpa criteria query using jsonb function jsonb_array_elements_text() in postrges

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jsonb, criteriaquery

I have a table **member** where **party** is one of the column of type jsonb. jsonb structure looks as below:

```
{
    "PE": [ "fefe046d-774d-4e8b-a74c-99c89e98a96f",
            "720bfde7-a8c0-404f-b746-d6929c9b1109",
            "409cc84a-a473-4945-9ec0-c09a2ae96395" ],
    "TE": []
}
```

I have written a query as below in native SQL, how to write the same query using jpa criteria?

```
select distinct id from public.member,jsonb_array_elements_text(party-> 'PE') where value  in ('fefe046d-774d-4e8b-a74c-99c89e98a96f','409cc84a-a473-4945-9ec0-c09a2ae96395')
```

Your response at the earliest would be appreciated.

Comment: Since that method only exists in one database anywhere, and not at all in JPQL (and hence JPA Criteria) then no you can't ... without calling the NATIVE SQL function. Any JPA docs would reveal that

Comment: cb.function() can not be used?

Comment: cb.function definitely can be used